# JetBrains Rider : How to reset settings in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jetbrains-ide, rider

Accidently deleted `RiderProjects` folder in Ubuntu. 
Now when I start a new project, no template is showing.
I tried uninstalling Rider by deleting `/opt/rider` folder and `~/Rider2018**` folder.
Even after installing rider again the templates are not showing up. How do I reset the rider settings?

Comment: Rider is not mentioned here .. but have a look anyway: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Tried It, didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

This helped me. I was missing mono. The following installs the mono requirements for .net core

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo apt-get install mono-xsp4
```

Comment: This definitely doesn't answer the question.